# Null Pointer exception thrown while initializing Airplay(airpush) ads

Tags: java, android, andengine, airpush

I am getting `NullPointerException` while I try to access `Airplay`(airpush google play version). when I call `airpush.startSmartWallAd();` ads page shows working and after that a new tab is open of web (in my opinion) and its says

> The sdcard is busy....

along with force close message of my game:

```
02-28 17:56:32.546: E/AndroidRuntime(9082): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 17:56:32.546: E/AndroidRuntime(9082): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 17:56:32.546: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):     at android.webkit.ZoomManager.onSizeChanged(ZoomManager.java:945)
02-28 17:56:32.546: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):     at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.onSizeChanged(WebViewClassic.java:5587)
02-28 17:56:32.546: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):     at android.webkit.WebView.onSizeChanged(WebView.java:2030)
02-28 17:56:32.546: E/AndroidRuntime(9082):     at android.view.View.setFrame(View.java:13926)
...................
```

Edit

Here i am initializing Airplay object.

if(airpush==null)

airpush=new AirPlay(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this, true);

airpush.startSmartWallAd();

And setting permissions in the manifest and have checked the key. Everything is fine
I have implemented AdCallListner as well and control goes inside each function of listener override functions.
If i unplugged the cable from pc and now The sdcard busy message is removed and something start downloading but error remains same Force close.
The error is occuring in their sample code as well.

Comment: space ghost i have updated the code, waiting for your reply

Answer (score -1):

Can you post more code please?

From first impression it looks like one of your objects is not initialized. That's what a NullPointerException indicates.

Look over your code and see if you've failed to initialize an object you're trying to use.